# Does Sculpt Spells apply to spells that have been reflected?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Sculpt Spells is a level 2 evocation wizard ability. Here's its text:

> Sculpt Spells
>
> Beginning at 2nd level, you can create pockets of
>   relative safety within the effects of your evocation spells. When you
>   cast an evocation spell that affects other creatures that you can see,
>   you can choose a number of them equal to 1 + the spell’s level. The
>   chosen creatures automatically succeed on their saving throws against
>   the spell, and they take no damage if they would normally take half
>   damage on a successful save.

Given the following scenario:

1. You and your target are 30 feet apart
2. You cast Fireball at the target
3. You "instruct" your Fireball to avoid you with Sculpt Spells
4. The target reflects the Fireball
5. You're struck by the Fireball

Does Sculpt Spells apply in this situation? Would you have to make the saving throw for the Fireball?

Comment: I added this as an answer but it got deleted, so I'll make note here.  I've since learned that there's no such thing as a de-facto "Spell Reflect", so the question (which asks for corroboration on an ability that doesn't exist) doesn't have an answer.  Or the answer is that there is no answer, whatever.

As far as I'm aware at this point, the only Spell Reflect in 5e is from the Spectator monster, the mechanics of which, in respect to Sculpt Spells, are explained below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fundamentally isn't a real question. It's asking about something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are referring to a monster ability such as the Spectator's **Spell Reflection** reaction, then we can look at the defined rule:

> If the spectator makes a successful saving throw against a spell, or a spell attack misses it, the spectator can choose another creature (including the spellcaster) it can see within 30 feet of it. **The spell targets the chosen creature instead of the spectator.** If the spell forced a saving throw, the chosen creature makes its own save. If the spell was an attack, the attack roll is rerolled against the chosen creature.

*p. 30 DMG 5e* (emphasis mine)

Let's look at the rule for **Sculpt Spells** again

> When you cast an evocation spell that affects other creatures that you can see, you can choose a number of them equal to 1 + the spell’s level. **The chosen creatures automatically succeed their saving throws against the spell**, and they take no damage if they would normally take half damage on a successful save.

The creatures chosen with the Scult Spells feature will still automatically save and take no damage from this spell as there is no new spell created by the Spell Reflection ability.

---

*Additional Note:* My answer is addressed to the original question, "Does Sculpt Spells apply to spells that have been reflected?" Regarding the specific scenario where the spell in question is *fireball*, a spectator could not use the Spell Reflection reaction as the ability states "The spell targets the chosen creature *instead* of the spectator." The *fireball* spell targets a point of origin for an area of effect and not the spectator directly.

Comment: It looks to me like the Spell Reflection ability is applicable only to spells that target the individual  (a chosen creature), not to area effect spells.  So the two effects do not overlap; they apply to different situations.

Comment: I believe an evoker could apply the effect of Sculpt Spells when casting the *immolation* spell. This spell forces a targetted creature to make a Dexterity saving throw and fulfills the requirements of Sculpt Spells as it is an evocation spell and it affects other creatures that you can see. In most cases, it would be impractical to use this effect for a single target spell but could be a smart tactic if a PC knew they were targetting a creature capable of reflecting spells.

Comment: You could offer a spell like magic missile or a single target spell as an example.

Comment: There is also the Ring of Spell Turning. Its mechanics are similar to the Spectator's ability.